# Encoding error when installing Keras on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to install Keras on Windows 10. I installed Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, CUDA 8.0, its second patch, cuDNN 6.0, PyCharm, Anaconda, Python 3.6.3 in this specific order.
I installed `tensorflow-gpu`.
I added `\path-to\Python\Python36\bin` to the `PATH` environment variable, and for the NVIDIA folders. Tensorflow works from the shell but not from the Anaconda prompt.
When I try to install Keras by using `pip install keras` from PowerShell I get the following error.

```
    PS C:\Users\myusr> pip install keras
    Collecting keras
      Downloading Keras-2.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (302kB)
        100% |████████████████████████████████| 307kB 553kB/s
    Collecting pyyaml (from keras)
      Downloading PyYAML-3.12.tar.gz (253kB)
        100% |████████████████████████████████| 256kB 553kB/s
    Collecting scipy>=0.14 (from keras)
      Downloading scipy-1.0.0-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl (30.8MB)
        100% |████████████████████████████████| 30.8MB 41kB/s
    Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in c:\users\myusr\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from keras)
    Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in c:\users\myusr\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from keras)
    Building wheels for collected packages: pyyaml
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyyaml ... error
      Failed building wheel for pyyaml
      Running setup.py clean for pyyaml
    Failed to build pyyaml
    Installing collected packages: pyyaml, scipy, keras
      Running setup.py install for pyyaml ... error
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\myusr\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
        return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
            UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 76: invalid start byte

            During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\myusr\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "c:\users\myusr\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
        prefix=options.prefix_path,
      File "c:\users\myusr\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
        **kwargs
      File "c:\users\myusr\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
        spinner=spinner,
      File "c:\users\myusr\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
        line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
      File "c:\users\myusr\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
        return s.decode('utf_8')
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 76: invalid start byte
```

What can I do?

Comment: Try to install pyyaml separately and see if it will give the same error. $ pip install pyyaml

Comment: Also try to update your setuptools: $ pip install --upgrade setuptools --ignore-installed

Comment: Thank you. The error output is still the same, it didn't work!

Comment: What language is your operating system using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is coming from pyyaml module. Based on the fact that from version 3.6 Python for Windows is using UTF-8 for it's console IO it leads to errors. In case of running a subprocess, it thinks that the output from subprocess will be also UTF-8... which is not the case.

There are 3 ways to fix this:

1. Use Python < 3.6 (e.g. 3.5.2)
2. Use locale.getpreferredencoding(False) for the encoding
3. Run a command from cmd/powershell: chcp . It will show the system default code, for example 936. Open Lib/site-package/pip/compat/**init**.py
   and around line 76 change

   ```
   return s.decode('utf_8')
   ```

   to

   ```
   return s.decode('cp936')
   ```

Comment: English/Italian. Are there any drawbacks (not only in python, also system-wise) on using option #2?
Thank you I'll try asap

Comment: Not any I would know about :) You are not setting, just getting.

Comment: I used method 1 and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same situation when installing Keras on my Windows 10 machine.

1) First step is to **install pyyaml** successfully, which works well with **easy_install** and no `UnicodeDecodeError` shows up

`easy_install pyyaml`

2) Try again installing **Keras**

`pip install keras`

3) You may get an odd error regarding your cached Keras install files:

`zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 for file 'tensorflow-1.8.0.data/purelib/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd'`

Simply add the no-cache directive

`pip install --no-cache-dir keras`